# What are the characteristics and verses of the Devi Bhagavata Purana mentioned by Bhaskararaya?

Tags: puranas, shloka, devi-bhagavata-purana, sri-vidya, bhaskararaya

Bhaskararaya was a great Sri Vidya Acharya from Southern India. Being from the same Sampradaya as Adi Shankaracharya, (whom he credits with spreading the Sampradaya in his Guptavati Bhashya on Sri Durga Saptashati), he was an ardent upholder of Advaita, which is evident from his reference to the Brahma Sutra 1.4.23 in his commentary on the Varivasya Rahasya. A great man, he authored many works/ commentaries on ancient traditional treatises.

Many of these works (some unavailable) find mention in his biography, Bhaskaravilasa by his disciple Jagannatha some of which are:- Caṇḍbhāskara on Vedanta (verse 42); Vādakautuhala and Bhattachandrodaya on Purva Mimamsa (verse 44 and 45); Smrititattva (verse 52); Sri Sukta Bhashyam (verse 60); **Saubhagyabhaskara Bhashya on the Sri Lalita Sahasranama** (verse 62); Guptavati Tika on Sri Durga Saptashati and many many more.

In the 27th verse of same biography it is written:

> देवीभागवतं नाम पुराणं प्रोक्तलक्षणम्। आनीय प्रकटीचक्रे दानी पात्रेष्वदाम्भिकः॥२७॥
>
> **He brought and made appear the characteristics of the Devi Bhagavata Purāṇa** (27)

He is credited with the popularisation of the Sri Devi Bhagavata Purāṇa. It is also said that he has quoted some 35 verses from the Purāṇa, in the above mentioned commentary on the Sri Lalita Sahasranama. Now the verses quoted by such a great man (as described above) would be from the authentic Purāṇa.

**Question**
I would like to know what characteristics of the Sri Devi Bhagavata Purāṇa, to match with Sri Vidya, that were taught by him (if any) in very brief.

As the main requirement, please provide a compilation of the verses alongwith meaning (if possible), of the Sri Devi Bhagavata Purāṇa quoted by Bhaskararaya in his Saubhagyabhaskara Bhashya. Also any other verses from the said Purāṇa from his many other works would be much appreciated.